# Can I load a web path from an external file

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an application thats uses HTML5 and there are many html pages that point to the same url, however, the url can change.

Is there a way that rather than pointing each individual html page to a url, that i can point them to a single file that contains a url, therefore only having to change the url from one location and individually?

I.E. 10 pages contain an iframe with src="http://www.google.co.uk" if I now wanted them to point to "http://www.yahoo.co.uk" I'd have to make that change 10 times instead of once. Could i create some kind of file so that src="webpath" instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external `javascript` file which will be used in all the ten pages and you , just, can edit the `javascript` file to load the same `iframe` in all the ten pages.

**All the 10 pages**:

```html
<script src="iframe-location.js"></script>
<body onload="loadIframe()">
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
```

**iframe-location.js** (External `js` file):

```js
//You just can change the iframe src
function loadIframe() {
  document.getElementById("frame").src = "https://bing.com";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use redirection using javascript

Create a resource that will be used by the 10 pages and that page will have the redirection

`window.location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com");`